# after training and testing, how do i handle new data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, train-test-split

i've got 2 questions. I have a dataset with a mix of categorical features and numerics. My aim is to predict the loan grade of an individual.

The steps I've taken for **dataset1** are as follows:

1) Dropped the categorical features from the dataframe
2) `Onehotencoded` the categorical features
3) `pd.concat` the categorical features back with the main dataframe and dropped the target variable
4) `train_test_split` into 70% for training and 30% for testing
5) applied PCA, `fit_transform` the training set and `transform` the test set
6) found that random forest worked, so i used `RandomForestClassifier` as the main algo
7) tested the model and had an accuracy score of 80%
8) tuned the model and improved it to 81%

Now I've got a new bunch of data coming in, lets call it **dataset2**. I repeated the steps from 1 to 3 with **ONLY** the new datasets. Next, I just dropped the target variable, and used `RF.predict()`. **I'm aware its wrong, and I think I should fit the algo but the shapes are different.** `Train_test_split` just **dataset2** alone to fit the algo doesnt make sense to me, then what is the purpose of **dataset1**? I apologize for being a noob but i'm very confused on how to handle and predict the variables with the new dataset.

Should i 1) re-train my model? If so, how should i go about doing it? 2) Do i concat the new **dataset2** under **dataset1**, and split it again? This was what I did for **dataset1**

```
RF = RandomForestClassifier() 
model = RF.fit(x_train1, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test1)
```

This was what i did for dataset2

```
new_pred= model.predict(x_test2)
```

If any of my steps are wrong, please feel free to let me know. And also please provide any solutions. I did try implementing a pipeline but I couldnt recreate the accuracy as before.

Any other solutions are welcomed.

Comment: you are not applying step no 5 for new data set, i.e PCA..

Comment: I think you don't have to re-train model if you model is fit and can use, you can try to add by adding dataset2 and re-trian but should get not much difference model between old and new one

you shall to re-trian when you model is getting old cann't response to new data anymore not just update data for traning

Comment: @qaiser, apologies i forgot to add that in, i did use it also, but the shapes were different.

Comment: @ThotsaphonSirikutta, its strange cos my accuracy is only 16% when i reused the model.

Comment: Something does not make sense to me : if dataset 2's shape is different from dataset1's shape, you can't trained it and use it the same way. For your prediction, you have to use data that are coherent with trainable examples you had

Comment: @YoannA. The dataset2's shape is different because i applied onehotencoding on categorical features. When i encoded just the categorical features on dataset1, i had 19 columns. When i encoded the categorical features on dataset2, i only had 16. I've got 3 extra columns on dataset1.

Answer (score 2):

Well it makes more sense for shapes.

What I can suggest, because it happen's to me sometimes, is to check about you're data distribution : what is your data from each dataset about ? I explained my self : I had the same problem once when I was classifying people on their hobbies. My train, dev, test set come from data i've obtained on people living in a city. But, some weeks later when I've tried my classifier on people living in the countryside, it did poorly. Indeed, the two datasets don't come from the same distribution.

I think maybe you might be facing the same problem. check your two datasets.

Comment: Noted! And how do you handle the situation if your data distribution is off? Do you just drop the new data completely? Or do you merge it with the old dataset, and retrain it? Sorry if it sounds like a stupid qn.

Comment: 1 - You merge all your datasets, shuffle them and train a new classifier. 2 - You train two classifiers